# how can I get the value of toggle check box

Tags: javascript, toggle

I want to get the value of toggle check box.
I mean, I want to get value of let me say '1' for ready and '0' for not ready.
how can I do that?
here is my code:

```
 <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you set an ID to the checkbox. Then listen to the changes.

```
<input id="my_checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="getValue()"...

function getValue() {
   var isChecked = document.getElementById('my_checkbox').checked;
   var the_value = isChecked ? 1 : 0;
   //do something with that value
}
```

See [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgo41tbo/1/)

Comment: I did it but unfortunately no results.
`<input type="checkbox" id="type" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"> `
`<script>$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#type').change(function(){
       alert(this.val());
});
});</script>

Comment: that `document.ready` is in jquery style. Do you have it included in your html?

Comment: plus `$(this).val()` won't do anything. If you want to go jquery style, write `alert($(this).is(":checked")); `

Comment: I included Jquery cdn. but it doesn't show any value or even alert
do you try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Everything worked well for me. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgo41tbo/)

Comment: it works without `data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">`.
and works with `<input type="checkbox" id="id">`.
but I want to use data-toggle to have a better style. when it click on read/not ready ?
is there any way to fix the problem of `data-toggle`?

Comment: I don't know the stuff behind data-toggle, but see [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgo41tbo/1/) for use with data-toggle.

Answer (score 0):

The following should yield 1 if the switch is checked and 0 if not:

```
let fxnn=()=>{
let x=document.getElementById('switch').checked

alert(x ? 1 : 0)
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/we05vrd8/4/)